# How to pass dynamic value in slice using in for loop

Tags: python, django

Hi I have object list and want to pass the variable dynamic:

```
{% for item in feed_item.feed_comment.all|slice:"6:10" %}

{% endfor %}
```

The above code is working fine but when I am passing dynamic value in slice then its giving
error.

```
{% for item in feed_item.feed_comment.all|slice:feed_item.feed_comment.count:perpagecomment %}

{% endfor %}
```

**Error**

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /home/feed/

'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for item in feed_item.feed_comment.all|slice: feed_item.feed_comment.count
```

Thanks

Comment: Related: [Django template slice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405305/django-template-slice)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but as far as I'm aware this is not possible.  You could build your own slice or even build a variable like this.  I think this would work.

```
(view)
feed_comments = feed_comment.objects.all()
feed_comment = feed_comment.objects.count()
your_variable = "0:%d" % (feed_comment)

(template)
{% for feed in feed_comments|slice:your_variable %}
```

Comment: {% for feed in feed_comments|slice:your_variable %} I have tested this but it is also giving error.Slice is working on constant values.

Comment: okay sorry, i was not able to test it.  is the error differnt?

Comment: Now it is showing 'int' object has no attribute 'split'.
When I use slice:"feed_item_count" in double quoete then it wont raise error but return all result.